# while visible how do i make this dialog prevent access to rest of the page content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

im trying to make a dialog such that while it is visible, it prevents access to page content. if i click accept the dialog should disappear is never re-presented on subsequent visits. if a disagree it should redirection to another site, and continually represent the dialog on next visits,  im having a lot of trouble with this i have the outline done but im having trouble to implement its functions.
this is what i have done

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <body>

    <div id= Cooky>

  <h2>Warning</h2>

   <p>site-usage requires the user’s acceptance of cookie usage before  progressing.</p>
<button id="button" onclick="toggleDiv('Cooky');">agree</button>
<button id="button" onclick="toggleDiv('Cooky');">diagree</button> 


</div>

<div>
 this is the rest of the wesbite<br>


this is the rest of the wesbite<br>

this is the rest of the wesbite<br>

</div>

</body>




<script type="text/javascript"           src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleDiv(divId) {
        $("#"+divId).toggle();
    }
</script>
```

the rest of the code is on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a02ma3x5/
please have a look
thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try with overlay, see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a02ma3x5/2/)

```
<div class="overlay active">
```

`.overlay.active {
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    z-index:1;
}`

```
 $('.overlay').toggleClass('active');
```